# Problema com o servidor web Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

eu digito o comando **rails server** ele dá esse erro aqui;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porque será que ele não soube o servidor web?

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Tenha certeza que você está no diretório correto. É um erro muito comum você criar um projeto `rails new nome_do_projeto` e em seguida dar `rails s`, mas você está fora do diretório do projeto.

Então basta você entrar no diretório ex: `cd nome_do_projeto` e ai sim dê um `rails s`

PASSO A PASSO:

```
rails new nome_do_projeto
cd nome_do_projeto
rails s
```

Utilize o comando `ls` sempre que possível para garantir que você esteja no diretório correto.